# When should I use axios for async calls and when only useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am confused right now. Learning js frontend and how to make API requests.
Till now, whenever I made an API call, I always used something, that let me handle an asynchronous request (`axios` or `thunk`).

But now I got a case, where I am making a request to my Firebase/Firestore and in the yt video, that I watched, only `useEffect` was used. Without any `async/await`, like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // snapshot - to check, if there is a change (like a new entry) in the database
  db.collection('products').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    setProducts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
  });
}, []);
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example code snippet

```
useEffect(() => {
  // snapshot - to check, if there is a change (like a new entry) in the database
  db.collection("products").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      setProducts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
  })
}, []);
```

`db.collection("products")` manages its own asynchronous event handling. When a "snapshot" event is received it invokes the `onSnapshot` callback and updates state. There is nothing to await on, especially since there is no value returned.

You should also note that `useEffect` hook callbacks are 100% ***synchronous code***, they *can't* be marked `async` and `await` any code calls. They can, however, call `async` functions that do their own awaiting and such.

#### About the questions in your title

Use a `useEffect` hook *any time* you want to issue any side-effect from the component lifecycle, like console logging state, make data fetches, dispatching actions. This is mostly due to the fact that the *entire* function body of a functional react component is to be considered a pure function. `useEffect` with dependencies is more akin to a class-based component's `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle methods. Alone they are just called as part of the react component lifecycle.

Use `axios`, or `fetch`, or any other data fetching code whenever you need to fetch *that* data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I see, that I should have in the first place be reading the documentation about onSnaphsot. And also for clarifying about useEffect using async functions.
So in this case it means, that there is already an async function used, named onSnapshot. Great.

Comment: @AaronErdwyn I suppose I should also make it a bit more clear, if it isn't already, that asynchronously processing/calling a function doesn't necessarily mean the code/function is `async`. Here `async` is a keyword that allows functions to `await` values to resolve (think Promise chains).

Answer (score 1):

1. useEffect() - It is a hook that allows us to perform side effects in functional components like network request etc.
2. Axios - It is just a library where we can make http request like fetch API in javascript and also axios is promise based.